# I cannot publish Dialog to Azure 'TypeError - Cannot read property 'AzureSubscriptionId' of undefined" [Bot Composer Framework]

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework

I cannot publish my dialogs in Bot Composer Framework version 2.1.1. We have created a new different Resource group and app services, since we have Production site and this one is for testing site. I have checked all the credentials of the bot and it is correct. (Microsoft AppId, keys etc.)

"TypeError - Cannot read property 'AzureSubscriptionId' of undefined"

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE: Microsoft supported me, and it looks like there's something wrong with my ARM access token and they reset it. it works fine now.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Microsoft supported me, and it looks like there's something wrong with my ARM access token and they reset it. it works fine now.**

Comment: Is it a solution? It seems it could be an edit of another part.

Comment: @FrançoisB. Microsoft Engineers supported me they just reset the token of my subscription ID, there is no error in my config. thank you

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423174)

Answer (score -1):

When you are trying to publish your bot framework to Azure we need to configure the settings as below:

When we generate APP ID and Password make sure that we are using `yourbotframework.azurewebsite.net/api/message` and post that you need to create Microsoft Id & Password and to be used in your code.

[image]

To get the `URI`
[image]

For more information please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation***:- [***Publish a bot to Azure from Composer***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot?tabs=v2x)

Comment: Yes i have those already, we have a chatbot running on Production site, and this one is for our testing site. I am not sure what is happening to our Resource group. i have created a new credentials for the resource group.

Comment: AFAIK, when we are trying to generate password at that moment may be we select local application URL instead of Azure.